# Connecting multiple tables with different foreign keys SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struggling in finding the solution on how to connect 5 different tables, but with different foreign keys. The table looks like that:

[image: DB example]

I need to write a query that would return all customers visit costs and payment differences (debt or overpay) and the last payment date on selected dates:

SELECT Cusomer ID, Name, Surname, SUM(Visit fee + materials price sum + service sum) - SUM(Payment amount) AS pay_diff, MAX(payment_date) WHEN DATE IS BETWEEN (LAST MONTH) AND (TODAY)

Expected Output choosing between 01-07-2021 and today:
[image]

Update: my SQL tables and db response:

customers

[image]

customer_visit

[image]

visit_services

[image]

visit_materials

[image]

customer_payments:

[image]

Query calculations:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select c.ID, c.Name, c.Surname
sum(cv.visit_fee) + sum(vm.Price_sum) + sum(vs.Service_sum) - sum(cp.Payment_amount) as pay_diff, max(payment_date)
from customer c
left join customer_visit cv
on c.ID = cv.customer_id
left join Visit_materials vm
on cv.ID = vm.Visit_ID
left join Visit_services vs
on cv.ID = vs.Visit_ID
left join Customer_payment cp
as c.ID = cp.Customer_id
where Payment_date >= '01-07-2021' 
group by c.ID, c.Name, c.Surname
```

I noticed that the column names are inconsistent (diagram vs. table samples), you may need to adjust according to actual DB. If you got future date data, you can use between '01-07-2021' and 'xx-xx-2021' inside where clause. I hope it helps. If you get errors, can you post a screenshot of the error message?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. Well, it does not show any errors, but I guess it gives duplicated answers. my customer id 1 had two visit fees 0.00 and 5.00 and it calculated the sum as 400.
he paid 134.40, but the answer was calculated as 5100.00 and I am not sure how to fix it...

Comment: Hey, can screenshot both raw data and joined result of this case?

Comment: done, I updated the problem with all screenshots, hope it will help

Comment: hi, I mean the full data set for 1 use case, e.g. id=1. Noticed your filter clause is > '01-05-2021', partial data cannot help to troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi, sorry for that.
I updated again with a new response. but it seems that the results haven't changed even if I delete when date part.